# Inaccessible array returned by Firefox WebExtensions browser.tabs.query(). Can someone explain why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Can someone explain to me what is going on here?  I am playing around with the Firefox WebExtensions API, and I am running into some rather strange behavior.  Here is some very simple to code to illustrate the issue.

I am querying for all pinned tabs in all windows and I am expecting that the global array `var pinned = [];` will be populated with the tab data/objects. However, things are a little screwy to say the least.  The array seems to be populated but the individual elements are not accessible using standard array notation `pinned[0]` returns `undefined`.  I am absolutely perplexed by this.

So what is going on here?  Is this an issue about scope or permissions?

Now the code ...

[manifest.json]

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "test",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/page-48_white.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "devtools_page": "test.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": { "48": "icons/page-48_white.png"},
    "default_title": "Test",
    "browser_style": true
  }
}
```

[background.js]

```
function createExtPage(){
  browser.tabs.create({ "url": "test.html" });
}
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(createExtPage);
```

[test.js]

```
var pinned = [];

browser.tabs.query({pinned: true})
  .then(tabs => {
    for (let [key, value] of tabs.entries() ) {
      console.log("Object " + key, value);
      pinned.push(value);
    }
  });

console.debug("All Pinned Tabs", pinned);
console.debug("First Pinned Tab", pinned[0]);
```

Now take a look at this output from the Firefox developer tools console.

```
  All Pinned Tabs
  []
    0: {…}
        active: false
        audible: false
        discarded: false
        favIconUrl: "http://www.crunchyroll.com/favicon.ico?v=1"
        height: 800
        hidden: false
        highlighted: false
        id: 149
        incognito: false
        index: 0
        isArticle: false
        isInReaderMode: false
        lastAccessed: 1522229700160
        mutedInfo: Object { muted: false }
        pinned: true
        sharingState: Object { camera: false, microphone: false }
        status: "complete"
        title: "Crunchyroll - Watch Naruto Shippuden, Bleach, Anime Videos and Episodes Free Online"
        url: "http://www.crunchyroll.com/"
        width: 1440
        windowId: 3
        __proto__: Object { … }
  ​
    1: {…}
        active: false
        audible: false
        discarded: false
        favIconUrl: "https://www.pandora.com/favicon.ico"
        height: 800
        hidden: false
        highlighted: false
        id: 145
        incognito: false
        index: 0
        isArticle: false
        isInReaderMode: false
        lastAccessed: 1522447564848
        mutedInfo: Object { muted: false }
        pinned: true
        sharingState: Object { camera: false, microphone: false }
        status: "complete"
        title: "All Along The Watchtower Radio - Now Playing on Pandora"
        url: "https://www.pandora.com/station/play/3395036678172411653"
        width: 1440
        windowId: 67
        __proto__: Object { … }
  ​
    2: {…}
        active: false
        audible: false
        discarded: false
        height: 800
        hidden: false
        highlighted: false
        id: 171
        incognito: false
        index: 1
        isArticle: false
        isInReaderMode: false
        lastAccessed: 1522398347238
        mutedInfo: Object { muted: false }
        pinned: true
        sharingState: Object { camera: false, microphone: false }
        status: "complete"
        title: "Debugging with Firefox Developer Tools"
        url: "about:debugging"
        width: 1440
        windowId: 67
        __proto__: Object { … }
    length: 3
  ​  __proto__: Array []

  First Pinned Tab undefined

  Object 0
    {…}
      active: false
      audible: false
      discarded: false
      favIconUrl: "http://www.crunchyroll.com/favicon.ico?v=1"
      height: 800
      hidden: false
      highlighted: false
      id: 149
      incognito: false
      index: 0
      isArticle: false
      isInReaderMode: false
      lastAccessed: 1522229700160
      mutedInfo: Object { muted: false }
      pinned: true
      sharingState: Object { camera: false, microphone: false }
      status: "complete"
      title: "Crunchyroll - Watch Naruto Shippuden, Bleach, Anime Videos and Episodes Free Online"
      url: "http://www.crunchyroll.com/"
      width: 1440
      windowId: 3
      __proto__: Object { … }

  Object 1
    {…}
      active: false
      audible: false
      discarded: false
      favIconUrl: "https://www.pandora.com/favicon.ico"
      height: 800
      hidden: false
      highlighted: false
      id: 145
      incognito: false
      index: 0
      isArticle: false
      isInReaderMode: false
      lastAccessed: 1522447564848
      mutedInfo: Object { muted: false }
      pinned: true
      sharingState: Object { camera: false, microphone: false }
      status: "complete"
      title: "All Along The Watchtower Radio - Now Playing on Pandora"
      url: "https://www.pandora.com/station/play/3395036678172411653"
      width: 1440
      windowId: 67
      __proto__: Object { … }

  Object 2
    {…}
      active: false
      audible: false
      discarded: false
      height: 800
      hidden: false
      highlighted: false
      id: 171
      incognito: false
      index: 1
      isArticle: false
      isInReaderMode: false
      lastAccessed: 1522398347238
      mutedInfo: Object { muted: false }
      pinned: true
      sharingState: Object { camera: false, microphone: false }
      status: "complete"
      title: "Debugging with Firefox Developer Tools"
      url: "about:debugging"
      width: 1440
      windowId: 67
      __proto__: Object { … }
```

Here is the really screwy thing.  If I type `pinned[0]` in the firefox developer tools console I get this result

```
pinned[0]
  {…}
    active: false
    audible: false
    discarded: false
    favIconUrl: "http://www.crunchyroll.com/favicon.ico?v=1"
    height: 800
    hidden: false
    highlighted: false
    id: 149
    incognito: false
    index: 0
    isArticle: false
    isInReaderMode: false
    lastAccessed: 1522229700160
    mutedInfo: Object { muted: false }
    pinned: true
    sharingState: Object { camera: false, microphone: false }
    status: "complete"
    title: "Crunchyroll - Watch Naruto Shippuden, Bleach, Anime Videos and Episodes Free Online"
    url: "http://www.crunchyroll.com/"
    width: 1440
    windowId: 3
    __proto__: Object { … }
```

What gives? Why can I access the array's elements from the console but not the code?

As you can see the array pinned is populated but I can't access the individual elements inside using the array.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an issue of asynchronous code and array reference.
Let's try and see how this goes, step by step :

1. You call `browser.tabs.query`. It returns a promise, **which is not resolved immediately**. Therefore you don't go into the `then` part for the time being, so the code execution goes on to the next part...
2. Which is `console.debug("All Pinned Tabs", pinned);`. You're logging an array, so you're giving `console.debug` a *reference to the array*, which is really important here. This reference won't change over time : when you declared the `pinned` array and when the script ends, the array reference will still be the same.
3. Then you move on to `console.debug("First Pinned Tab", pinned[0]);`. At this point, the promise handler has not been executed yet, thererefore `pinned` is still empty and `pinned[0]` actually is `undefined`. That's why `undefined` gets logged.
4. The promise resolves: you go through the `then` handler, receive the tabs list as argument and push the tabs to your `pinned` array.

Remember, your first `console.debug` logged the array *based on the array reference, that didn't change over time*. When you're viewing the array in the console afterwards, the array has since been populated and what you access in the console is the array in its final state. That's why the log of the whole array does print the array itself.

#### Let's make sure of this

...with a little test: at step 2, instead of logging the `pinned` array itself, let's log the `id` of all elements currently in `pinned`.

```
var pinned = [];

browser.tabs.query({pinned: true})
  .then(tabs => {
    for (let [key, value] of tabs.entries() ) {
      console.log("Object " + key, value);
      pinned.push(value);
    }
  });

// will log an empty array since pinned tab is still empty,
// therefore, mapping tab ids will return an empty array
console.warn("All Pinned Tabs", pinned.map((t) => t.id));
// still undefined, nothing changed here
console.warn("First Pinned Tab", pinned[0]);
```

Here's what you should get:

```
All Pinned Tabs : Array []
First Pinned Tab undefined
```

#### How to deal with it?

A solution is to chain another promise at the end of the first one *(which is made possible because each `then` handler returns a new promise, so you can chain them)*, like this :

```
var pinned = [];

browser.tabs.query({pinned: true})
  .then(tabs => {
    for (let [key, value] of tabs.entries() ) {
      console.log("Object " + key, value);
      pinned.push(value);
    }
  }).then( () => {
    // ✓ [1,4,3,2] or anything matching your tabs ids
    console.debug("All Pinned Tabs", pinned.map((t) => t.id));
    // ✓ First tab object: { ... } 
    console.debug("First Pinned Tab", pinned[0]);
  });
```

And now you do get the expected result:

```
All Pinned Tabs Array(4) [ 1, 4, 3, 2 ]
First Pinned Tab Object { id: 1, index: 0, windowId: 3, highlighted: false … }
```

Note that instead of manipulating a global variable for the array, you could make the first promise return an array that would be the argument for the second promise.